# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fxRateRecordDate' of undefined thrown

Tags: angular

I have a component and model for that component so i have added a property and getting the data for that property from component.ts file.

when i run unit test case i get this error : Cannot read property 'fxRateRecordDate' of undefined thrown

I made the property optional as well but it doesn't work.

i am also check if in the object that property exist or not but still get this error

```
 if (data.checkcol!== undefined)
          this.checkcol = data.checkcol!=null?formatDate(data.checkcol, 'shortDate', 'en-US', 'undefined'):'';
        else
          this.checkcol = '';
```

Please tell me what is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Your error is saying **Cannot read property 'fxRateRecordDate' of undefined thrown**

this means data is `undefined` check first data has something or not

Also put this condition in your if statement

```
if (data !== undefined && data.checkcol!== undefined){
       this.checkcol = data.checkcol!=null?formatDate(data.checkcol, 'shortDate', 'en-US', 'undefined'):'';
} else{
}
```